Finding the Taylor Series of $\log_b(x)$
So, I learnt recently that the Taylor Series formula is :
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n}$
And I wanted to find the taylor series of $\log_b(x)$ knowing that $(\log_b(x))'=\frac{1}{x\ln(b)} \cdots\cdots (\star)$ .
So starting by making the taylor series of $\ln(x)$ at the desired point I want to get the logarithm at, I got this :
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-a)^n}{na^n}}$
And then, using the $(\star)$ I got this :
$\log_b(x)=\frac{1}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x(b-a)^n}{na^{n-1}}}} $
And making $x=a$ (Because $a$ from the first was the desired point I was going to xalculate the logarithm, i.e. $\log_b(a)$ ) we have :
$\log_b(a)=\frac{1}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(b-a)^n}{na^{n-1}}}} $
That did not work, troubleshooting the problem, I found that the taylor series of $\ln(x)$ was incorrect,can you help me please ? Thanks .

$\log x=-\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^k(-1+x)^k}k$, then use the change of base formula

@SineoftheTime how ?

$\log_b(x)=\frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$ so basically, your desried will be the expansion of $\ln (x)$ multiplied by the reciprocal of $\ln b$.
If you take $a=1$, you'll get
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^n}$$
Now $f^n(x)$ for $\log_b x$ is $\frac{(-1)^n(n-1)!}{(\ln b )x^n}$, so substitution gives simply
$$\log_b(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(\ln b)n}(x-1)^n
$$, but this is for $|x|<1$.
For $x>1$,we take $\frac 1x <1$, and calculate the series, but $\log_b\bigg(\frac 1x\bigg)=-\log_b x$, so you'll get the negative value of your desired result.  So basically if $x=a>1$,
$$-\log_b(a)=\frac{1}{\ln b}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\bigg(\frac 1a-1\bigg)^n
\\
\implies\log_b(a)=\frac{1}{\ln b}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\bigg(\frac 1a-1\bigg)^n$$

Thanks for answering, but can you also give me the taylor series of ln(b) (not when a=0) so I can have the value of ln(b) also as a taylor series .

@hasandarwish just put the value of $x=b$ and you'll get it.

Here is another way of proceeding than calculating all the derivatives $f^{(n)}(x)$.
First notice that $a=0$ is not suitable in our case since the function is not defined in this point, you could choose any $a\neq 0$ but $a=1$ for the logarithm is generally a nice choice because $\ln(1)=0$ plays a particular role for this function (it is its only zero).
So set $u=x-1$ and we will try to find a power series in $u$ for $f(u)=\log_b(1+u)$
On the other hand the analytic form $f(u)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nu^n$
Since $f'(u)=\frac 1{\ln(b)(1+u)}$ we want to identify the coefficients of the series for
$(1+u)\ln(b)f'(u)$ with the series $1=1+0u+0u^2+0u^3+\cdots$

I rewrite $B=\ln(b)$ for convenience.
$\begin{align}(B+Bu)f'(u)
&=(B+Bu)\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nu^{n-1}
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}Bna_nu^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}Bna_nu^{n}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}B(n+1)a_{n+1}u^{n}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}Bna_nu^{n}\\
&=Ba_1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(B(n+1)a_{n+1}+Bna_n\Big)u^{n}\
\end{align}$
Notice also $a_0=f(0)=0$
By identification with the $1$ series we get
$\begin{cases}Ba_1=1\\B(n+1)a_{n+1}+Bna_n=0\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}a_1=\frac 1{\ln(b)}\\a_{n+1}=-\frac{n}{n+1}a_n\quad\forall n\ge 1\end{cases}$

And this solves to $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n\ln(b)}\quad\forall n\ge 1$


Wow this is so cool
